# Where are the heroes of Faerûn during Tyranny of Dragons according to other adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, lore

I know that as the DM I can make up whatever I want and put the heroes of Faerûn wherever I choose in the story.  What I am looking for is answers that are in other modules (published adventures) that I do not own yet.

For example:  I think Drizzt shows up in *Out of the Abyss*, so I can hint as to where he is during the counsel meeting in *Rise of Tiamat*.

The reason I ask is that I know that my players will be asking where they (the heroes) are and also will want to know: *why aren't they helping*?

Specific heroes I am interesting in are:  Elminster, Minsc, Farideh, Isteval, and the Grey Hand enforcers.

Comment: This is definitely the right site for this kind of question. Just be aware that lore questions like this sometimes sit around for a bit before a good answer shows up as the information isn't always easily available.

Comment: IIRC, It's a Baenre that shows up in OOtA, not Drizzt.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up David! Yea, I am not sure where I heard that Drizzt helps in that adventure, so that could be right, John.

Comment: Yep. John's right. I just did a search of DNDBeyond's compendium for their names; Drizzt is mentioned a few times but doesn't seem to appear, unlike the matron mother of House Baenre (and another Baenre who apparently fled Menzoberranzan).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, let's see what we can find...

## Timeline Background

The *Tyranny of Dragons* storyline kicks off in 1489 DR. *Princes of the Apocalypse* happens in 1491 DR. The pre-plot of *Out of the Abyss* got kicked off around 1485/1486, but the module itself doesn't specify when it actually happens - Chris Perkins said it happens 'right about the same time' as ToD and PotA.

## Elminster

The Sage of Shadowdale does not lead a dull life. 1487 DR covered the events of the end of the Second Sundering, in which Elminster was intimately involved. He was quite busy preventing other people from ascending to the position of god of magic, and in restoring Mystra to her former power (recorded in the novel *The Herald*). In the year 1491, when PotA was happening, Elminster was in Waterdeep helping Larael Silverhand investigate the murder of several Masked Lords (recorded in the novel *Death Masks*).

What he was doing in the intervening years is unknown.

## Minsc

Minsc is a character that only exists in video games, and video game tie-in comics (particularly *Baldur's Gate* and *Neverwinter*). In the *Neverwinter* game, events take place that do not match with the events taking place in published modules.

Minsc is one such case. The *Neverwinter* game's Module 6 (*Elemental Evil*) places Minsc working alongside the Emerald Enclave working against the Cults of Elemental Evil. Events in the game played out quite differently than they did in the published campaign.

Because he exists in a world that doesn't match up with the current published adventures, one cannot say what he was up to during the published adventures.

## Farideh

We have no information whatsoever on the location or state of Farideh post 1486 DR. This is the time period in which the last book in the *Brimstone Angels* series was written, so we have no further information on what she is up to in the time period that the 5E published adventures are taking place.

## Sir Isteval

Isteval turns up in the *Tyranny of Dragons* storyline. He is the representative of Daggerford for the Lord's Alliance at the Council of Waterdeep. It is emphasized that Isteval is a *retired* adventurer who now walks with a cane and has settled into a more political and advisory role... explaining his absence from actively helping out.

> He also works "secretly" for Cormyr, but is too honorable to actually keep it a secret.

## Gray Hands

Presumably, Force Grey is still around, as they are mentioned in the *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* adventure. However, Force Grey's operations are mostly confined to Waterdeep and its surrounding areas. While this is not directly supported, it is likely that they are being retained by Waterdeep to tackle any threats that directly approach Waterdeep, while other Adventurers are supported and dispatched to deal with more distant threats.

One callout of note, however, is that an auxiliary member of Force Grey shows up in the *Storm King's Thunder* adventure.

> Harshnag the Frost Giant

## Drizzt

The storyline of Drizzt's novels actually contradicts the events of *Out of the Abyss*. In this storyline...

> Only Demogorgon was summoned, and Drizzt (with a lot of psionic support) is the one who 'kills' him back to the Abyss.

Because his story contradicts the existing modules, it is hard to place him within them. However, this 'version' of the OOtA story takes place in 1486DR, technically prior to all the published campaigns. Which places him...

> Living in Luskan/Gauntlgrym, happily married to Cattie-brie, who is pregnant with his child.

Or, perhaps, off on some other adventure that hasn't yet been written.

## The Out-of-lore answer

Just so this is here...the obvious answer for 'where were they' is 'somewhere else, so the PCs can have the spotlight.' If Elminster and his allies showed up to try to solve the problem, there wouldn't be much left for the PCs to do.

Comment: Minsc is actually canonicalised in the 4e D&D Encounters adventure *Murder in Baldur's Gate* and again in the 5e module *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*. In the former a statue of Minsc & Boo exists in Baldur's Gate's marketplace, and in the latter (describing as of 1492 DR) it transpires that the statue was actually Minsc & Boo in petrified form, dispelled "recently" - so Minsc was presumably petrified in Baldur's Gate during the events of Tyranny of Dragons.

Answer (score 1):

Our DM had Isteval show up as part of the council meeting not sure if that is written as part of the story or he added it. but he did nothing to help us in our fight.

Comment: Isteval is indeed in Rise of Tiamat: https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/rot/introduction#SirIsteval