# Does Minsc appear in any 5e pen & paper adventures?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, lore

Does Minsc appear in any 5e pen & paper adventures?

I believe that Minsc did appear in [a 4e adventure](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/murder-baldurs-gate), but this question is for Fifth Edition. I found the question ["Where are the heroes of Faerûn during Tyranny of Dragons according to other adventures?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133756/48249), but it's a couple years old now and I'd like to know if Minsc has appeared any adventures since then.

Comment: Does being a statue in Baldur's Gate count as being in an adventure?

Comment: Note that ["Murder in Baldur's Gate"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/160318/Murder-in-Baldurs-Gate-5e) includes monster/NPC stats for 3.5e, 4e, and 5e - it was released during the 5e playtest: "Playtesting D&D Next. [...] Now Encounters was taking the next step with Season 15's "Murder in Baldur's Gate". The adventure itself was system-neutral, but Wizards included stats for D&D 3.5e, 4e, and 5e in the "Monster Statistics" book."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Minsc is mentioned, although doesn't feature as an actual character, in *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*

As you noted, Minsc is mentioned in passing in the D&D Encounters module *Murder in Baldur's Gate* (written for 3.5e, 4e, and the "D&D Next" 5e playtest), specifically that there is a statue of him and Boo in the The Wide, the great marketplace in the Upper City. This detail is featured again in *BG:DiA*, where it is explained that what had been presumed to be a statue was, in fact, actually the petrified characters themselves - and at some point in the years between *MiBG* and *BG:DiA* [they were cured and set to wandering the world again](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/bgdia/baldurs-gate-gazetteer#TheWide):

> ***Statue of Minsc and Boo.*** For years the Wide hosted one of the city’s most cherished landmarks: the Beloved Ranger, a statue of a powerful warrior in plate mail wearing a cheerful grin and cradling a hamster in his hands. Recently, though, the statue was revealed to be the Rashemi hero, Minsc, and his “miniature giant space hamster” companion, Boo, trapped under the effects of petrifying magic. When the magic was dispelled, it freed the heroes to walk the world once more but robbed the Wide of a bit of its charm. The merchants complained loudly, and a replacement statue of Minsc and Boo was promptly commissioned and set atop the pedestal where the actual heroes stood for years.

However, he does not otherwise feature in the adventure. It seems likely that this specific detail is a way of keeping the character available for use in future 5e material - establishing that Minsc & Boo have been petrified for the last hundred or so years neatly avoids the issue that a normal human like Minsc who was active in the late 1300s DR should have been dead (or at best *extremely* old) by the 1480s and 90s, when 5e's FR material is set. (As a miniature giant space hamster, we can probably assume that Boo's lifespan isn't an issue.)

### He's also seen as an easter egg in an illustration in *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*

The section of *W:DH*'s introduction describing [The Yawning Portal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/introduction#TheYawningPortal) tavern includes a cartoon illustration of the tavern's layout full of depictions of famous characters of D&D and Realms lore enjoying the tavern's attractions. Minsc and Boo are number 22, located between Volothamp "Volo" Geddarm and Krydle (a character who features alongside Minsc & Boo in the IDW D&D comics).

[image: Minsc and Boo at the Yawning Portal.]

Of course, this depiction doesn't imply anything canonical about Minsc & Boo's activities or whereabouts.

### Minsc and Boo feature in WotC's *The Descent* livestream event

If you widen the net a little, Minsc doesn't feature in any other officially published written material, but his character *did* appear in Wizards of the Coast's 2019 live play livestream event [*The Descent*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqLwCAt7Gbc), in which he is found trapped in Avernus with a motley collection of other heroes and eventually manages to escape back to Baldur's Gate (though the canonicity of this adventure may be questionable).

Here he was played by Jim Zub, who had previously written the character in the IDW D&D comics. Boo was played by Matt Mercer, of *Critical Role*.

[image: Minsc and Boo, portrayed by Jim Zub and Matt Mercer]

Comment: He also appears in the big cartoon drawing in _Waterdeep: Dragon Heist_.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard good spot, I hadn't noticed him there before!

Answer (score 4):

### Minsc appears in *Heroes of Baldur's Gate*

[*Heroes of Baldur's Gate*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/269398/Heroes-of-Baldurs-Gate-5e) is a 5e adventure that takes place in the year 1369 DR, shortly after the events of the original *Baldur's Gate* video game. It is designed by James Ohlen, who was the lead designer of the video game, and the DM of the tabletop sessions where the character of Minsc originated.

Comment: Good find, and James Ohlen certainly has some right to the character, though it should be pointed out that this is not an official WotC product, so probably should not be taken as FR canon.